# Why doesn't mongoose aggregate method return all fields of a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following document

```json
    [
      {
        "_id": "624713340a3d2901f2f5a9c0",
        "username": "fotis",
        "exercises": [
          {
            "_id": "624713530a3d2901f2f5a9c3",
            "description": "Sitting",
            "duration": 60,
            "date": "2022-03-24T00:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "_id": "6247136a0a3d2901f2f5a9c6",
            "description": "Coding",
            "duration": 999,
            "date": "2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "_id": "624713a00a3d2901f2f5a9ca",
            "description": "Sitting",
            "duration": 999,
            "date": "2022-03-30T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ],
        "__v": 3
      }
    ]
```

And I am executing the following aggregation (on [mongoplayground.net](https://www.mongoplayground.net/))

```json
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "_id": "624713340a3d2901f2f5a9c0"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          exercises: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$exercises",
              as: "exercise",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$exercise.description",
                  "Sitting"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          limit: 1
        }
      }
    ])
```

And the result is the following

```json
    [
      {
        "_id": "624713340a3d2901f2f5a9c0",
        "exercises": [
          {
            "_id": "624713530a3d2901f2f5a9c3",
            "date": "2022-03-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "Sitting",
            "duration": 60
          },
          {
            "_id": "624713a00a3d2901f2f5a9ca",
            "date": "2022-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "Sitting",
            "duration": 999
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

So my first question is why is the **username** field not included in the result?

And the second one is why aren't the **exercises** limited to 1? Is the **limit** currently applied to the whole user document? If so, is it possible to apply it only on exercises subdocument?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Question

When you use `$project` stage, then only the properties that you specified in the stage will be returned. You only specified `exercises` property, so only that one is returned. NOTE that `_id` property is returned by default, even you didn't specify it.

---

#### Second Question

`$limit` is also a stage as `$project`. You can apply `$limit` to the whole resulting documents array, not to nested array property of one document.

---

#### Solution

In `$project` stage, you can specify `username` filed as well, so it will also be returned. Instead of `$limit`, you can use `$slice` to specify the number of documents that you want to be returned from an array property.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "624713340a3d2901f2f5a9c0"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "username": 1,
      "exercises": {
        "$slice": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$exercises",
              "as": "exercise",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$exercise.description",
                  "Sitting"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://www.mongoplayground.net/p/onxgSHQNSbn)

Comment: So the only way to limit a subdocument's size is doing it inside the code?

Comment: You can do it with MongoDB query as well. I updated my answer. Can you check it?